# What is the error in my code that list all the tabs in a file?

Tags: excel, vba

I want my code to pick up a file (file 2) and then list out all the tabs in that file in my current spreadsheet ("Input_tab" from file1). The code is not making creating the list. What is the error in my code?

```
Sub ListSheets()

Dim FilePicker As FileDialog
Dim mypath As String
Dim sheet_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1)
Set FilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FilePicker
        .Title = "Please Select a File"
        .ButtonName = "Confirm"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            mypath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            End
        End If
    End With
    
Workbooks.Open Filename:=mypath

sheet_count = Sheets.Count

For i = 1 To sheet_count
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Is this your exact code? `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1)` looks off.

Comment: Usually, you tell us that the error that occurs is `Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch` in the line `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1)`. In the VBE Project Explorer window, if you can identify a worksheet with e.g. `Sheet1 (Data)`, then `Data` is the worksheet's (tab) name and `Sheet1` is its code name (they can be the same). If the worksheet is in the workbook containing the code (`ThisWorkbook`), to reference it, you can use either `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")` or `Set ws = Sheet1` or just use `Sheet1` instead of the `ws` variable in the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with multiple workbooks (or really all the time) you should always be explicit about what (eg) `Sheets` collection you want to refer to (ie. in which workbook?)

This works for me

```vb
Sub ListSheets()
    
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim i As Long 'prefer Long over Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    mypath = GetFilePath("Please Select a File", "Confirm")
    If Len(mypath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'hide opening workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=mypath, ReadOnly:=True) 'get a reference to the opened workbook
    ws.Cells(1, 1).value = mypath '<<<
    For i = 1 To wb.Sheets.Count
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) = wb.Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
    wb.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub

'return user-selected file path
Function GetFilePath(TitleText As String, ButtonText As String) As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = TitleText
        .ButtonName = ButtonText
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then GetFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This worked for me. Is there any way I can print out the path of the selected file in my set spreadsheet? I attempted a print function within  the selection of the file dialogue but it gives back an error.

Comment: See edit above for adding the path